# The maximal complete bipartite subgraphs of the partition graph $\mathcal{P}(3^3)$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The concept of a partition graph is similar to the Kneser graph concept.

> Every vertex of a **partition graph** $\mathcal{P}(g^g)$ is a partition of $\{1,2, ..., g^2 \}$ into $g$ cells of size $g$. Two vertices $u$ and $v$ are adjacent if the intersection of each cell of $u$ with each cell of $v$ be nonempty.

I am working on $\mathcal{P}(3^3)$. The vertices of this graph are partitions of $\{1,2, ..., 9\}$ into $3$ cells of size $3$, and two vertices $u$ and $v$ are adjacent if each cell of $u$ has an element in each cell of $v$.

I am looking for all maximal complete bipartite subgraphs of this graph. I have already managed to find $K_{1,36}$ (th degree of each vertex is $36$), $K_{2,2}$, $K_{4,4}$, $K_{6,4}$, $K_{2,12}$.

I am not looking for the number of complete bipartite subgraphs, I need to find all maximal complete bipartite subgraphs. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation here is as follows. (Excuse me for repeating your conclusions.)

1. In fact, in the graph $G$ there exists a complete subgraph $K_{1,36}$ simply because the degree of each vertex of the graph $G$ is $36$.
2. Then there exists a subgraph $K_{2,12}$ and no subgraph $K_{2,n}$ with $n>12$.
3. There exists a subgraph $K_{4,6}$ and no subgraphs $K_{4,n}$ with $n>6$.
4. There are no subgraphs $K_{m,n}$ with $m\leq n$ and $m>4$ and $K_{3,n}$ with $n>6$.

This follows from this consideration.
For each fixed vertex $v$ there exists a set $U$ of vertices $G$ such that $|U|=27$ and $v,x$ have exactly $12$ common neighbors for each $x\in U$ and no more than $4$ neighbors for each $x\notin U$.

Then all complete bipartite subgraphs containing a fixed vertex $v$ and several vertices of $U$ are easily computed.

To summarize, you have actually listed all possible complete bipartite subgraphs of $G$. Apparently, if $G$ contains a subgraph $K_{m,n}$, then $G$ also contains a subgraph $K_{r,s}$ for any $r\leq m$ and $s\leq n$.

I will add more: this is a remarkable question.

**Sketch of the proof.**

Since the group of permutations $S_9$ lies in the group of automorphisms of the graph $G$, that is, $S_n\leq\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, we can assume that $v=(123)(456)(789)$.

Denote by $N_G(v,x)$ the set of all common neighbors of $v$ and $x$.
It is not difficult to prove that $|N_G(v,x)| =12$ if $x$  has the form $(123)(\cdots)(\cdots)$ or $(\cdots)(456)(\cdots)$ or $(\cdots)(\cdots)(789)$.

If $x$  has the form $(1\cdot\cdot)(2\cdot\cdot)(3\cdot\cdot)$, then $|N_G(v,x)|=2$.

If $x$  has the form $(12\cdot)(3\cdot\cdot)(\cdots)$ or $(13\cdot)(2\cdot\cdot)(\cdots)$ or $(23\cdot)(1\cdot\cdot)(\cdots)$
and the last bracket is not $(456)$ or $(789)$, then $|N_G(v,x)|=4$.

It follows that if the vertices $v, x_1,\ldots,x_s$, $s\geq1$, have more than four common neighbors, then they all have a common cell. We can assume that the common cell is $(123)$.

There are $10$ vertices having cell $(123)$ including $v$. We can assume that $x_1=(123)(457)(689)$ (for the third time we use that $S_n\leq\operatorname{Aut}(G)$). Now there are $8$ possibilities for choosing $x_2$. I haven't come up with anything other than a brute force, but the brute force is very small. The result is $|N_G(v,x_1,x_2)|\leq6$.
And so on.

Comment: It seems a remarkable answer too. Thanks. 
Some points do not make sense to me.  How did you derive the fourth conclusion? What if we have $v$ and two other vertices of $U$ like $a$ and $b$ at one side of our bipartite subgraph? We know $v$ has 12 common neighbours with each $a$ and $b$, what if 7 of them be the common neighbours of all three vertices $v$, $a$, and $b$?
Also, this claim: "Then all complete bipartite subgraphs containing a fixed vertex v and several vertices of U are easily computed". How do you make the bipartite subgraphs?

Comment: @Inez thank you for appreciating my answer. I have supplemented it with brief proofs.

Comment: thank you. your explanations were very helpful.